# Preact/Compat in PreactX - ReferenceError: h is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, preact

I have a very simple React application (doesn't actually do anything yet).

I've installed latest preactX (currently 10.4.1), and according to the docs this is now shipped with preact/compat, which is the library I need to be able to use all my react goodness.

### My current setup:

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "prod": "webpack --mode=production",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.6",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.9.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "preact": "^10.4.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1"
  }
```

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    presets:[
        "@babel/preset-env", //this was here before preact
        "@babel/preset-react" //this was here before preact
    ],
    plugins: [
        ["@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx", {pragma: "h", pragmaFrag: "Fragment"}] //this is the new preact bit
      ]
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/app.js"),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: "babel-loader"
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/index.html' ),
            filename: 'index.html'
        }),
    ],
    resolve: { // added this resolve section for the preact/compat alias
        alias : {
            "react": "preact/compat",
            "react-dom/test-utils": "preact/test-utils",
            "react-dom": "preact/compat",
        }
    }
};
```

**app.js ( containing react bits )**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <button>This is the start of my react app</button>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

### The problem

Now, what I assumed preact/compat did was allow me to continue coding as if I was using preact. This may be a completely incorrect assumption but I still need to be told where im going wrong as when I run a prod webpack and import my bundle.js I get the following:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: h is not defined
    at Module.<anonymous> (bundle.js:1)
    at n (bundle.js:1)
    at bundle.js:1
    at bundle.js:1
```

To get it to work I can change the ReactDOM.render... line in app.js to use the preact render function and just import preact instead. However I thought the whole point of preact/compat was so that I didn't have to do this?

Answer (score 10):

Using [React Automatic Runtime](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx#react-automatic-runtime-1) feature in babel should fix the issue for preact.

Add these babel configs to the project.

```js
// babel config
["@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx"], {
  "runtime": "automatic",
  "importSource": "preact"
}]
```

*Note:* This support was added in babel v7.9.0

*Source:* [preact-compat Github issue](https://github.com/preactjs/preact-compat/issues/541#issuecomment-750382448)

Answer (score 2):

adding 'import {h} from 'preact';' seems to solve the problem. But again, I'm unsure if this is how its intended to be used so clarification would be nice, even though this is a solution.

I guess preact/compat converts the '**ReactDOM.render**' line to something like '**render(h(De, null), document.....**', but I assumed preact/compat would handle the import of h for me.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {h} from 'preact';

class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <button>This is the start of my react app</button>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```